# How to format cell value from number to date / or plain text in Sheets so if formula with defined values works

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, date-format

I had this IF formula that grouped my years in certain groups, but now that I've changed how I extract year from data (so it covers other types of "data" formats or other format outliers in data set) its not working anymore. I've tried formatting it to date, and it works but not for just years (haven't even got to the other outliers). Can't make it work if I first regexextract year based on digit format and then try to format it from Sheets options. In the end I want to be able to group the years I extract into year groups. This [sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i9DHfl4eYKBKXHOFMmuDTVijjjmcARm6TT_C8aSVYac/edit#gid=0) should make more sense.

Regex I'm using:

```
=IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(D2,"\d\d\d\d"),IF(REGEXMATCH(D2,"century")=TRUE,REGEXEXTRACT(D2,"\d\d"),"Check"))
```

Not working with my year group formula:

```
=IF(E2<2000,"pre-2000",IF(AND(E2>=2000,E2<=2010),"2000-2010",IF(AND(E2>=2011,E2<=2016),"2011-2016",IF(AND(E2>=2017,E2<=2021),"2017-2021",IF(AND(E2<>"No year found",E2>2021),"post-2021","Check")))))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

try in H2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(G2:G="",,IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(G2:G, "\d{4}")*1)))
```

[image]

---

and try in i2:

```
=INDEX(IF(G2:G="",,IFNA(VLOOKUP(H2:H, 
 {-10000, "pre-2000"; 
    2000, "2000-2010"; 
    2011, "2011-2016"; 
    2017, "2017-2021";
    2021, "post-2021"}, 2, 1))))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! that works really nice, more logical than my formula. What is "*1" for the IFNA?

Comment: @DeboraS. in 1st formula 1 is not part of IFNA. it's a standalone value that multiplies the regex because regex is able to work only with text string so by *1 we turn extracted year/string/text into the real number/ numeric value. in 2nd formula 1 is the 4th argument of VLOOKUP and meaning of it is as follows: approximate mode  - eg. if the number is larger or equal than specified. it will fall back on the lowest specified value.